# Securing Password Authentication Through Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a login page using ajax request for user authentication. Its mean password entered by user is send as From Data on ajax request as plain text. My sent data is easy to open if someone using sniffing tools.

I'm sure the best solution for my problem is using HTTPS, and my company planned to used that. But i know that not easy for use HTTPS, at least need a time. I try to encrypt my data but i can't found encryption function that support both of PHP and JavaScript. I try to send password through session but i can't found way to set session variable from javascript.

Any solution for my problem ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there would be no good way to encrypt the info this way (even if you found a library for both JS and PHP) because a hacker could just examine your JS code, see the encryption scheme, and decrypt the stolen info.

Comment: I wonder if the new Crypto extensions would handle this. But as @General_Twyckenham said, I don't think you have much option today.

Comment: Yes, that's very confusing me. I'm not sure it secure if i used my own encryption. It's possible using cookie for parse data to server. But, is it secure to use cookie for send data ?

Comment: @AdrianUsagi No it's not secure to use a cookie to send data.  Cookie values get sent via a plain text request header (Cookie)

Comment: Oh, i see... Thanks for all of your response guys..

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no good solution to your problem except using https.

Comment: Yes, sure i will use HTTPS, Maybe implement HTTPS not that hard, but still need time. But my system must be always online right ? I just want to protect my system meanwhile waiting HTTPS implemented.

Comment: @AdrianUsagi check out http://www.jcryption.org/ , could get you by until you get SSL setup

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, HTTPS is the only way to secure your data from middle-man attacks. And it is not that hard to implement.

encrypting, although it is good to 'conceal' data, is not a secure way to protect. Besides, if a hacker has access to your JS code, they he knows how the password was encrypted.

Comment: Yes, sure i will use HTTPS, Maybe implement HTTPS not that hard, but still need time. But my system must be always online right ? I just want to protect my system meanwhile waiting HTTPS implemented.